# Are Key Changes Worthwhile?

Tags: key

There are lots of pop type songs which include key changes. Not modulations, but key changes which take the song up a semitone usually for another chorus, etc.

Listening to them, that key change gets lost in two bars maximum, when the rest of the song continues. So, for a lot of fuss for the writer and maybe the musicians, there's such a small pay-off, I question whether it's a worthwhile trick.

How can a song's change of key be made more notable? Some listeners don't even realise a key change has occurred, so is it such a good feature to include?

Comment: No-one can decide whether it's really 'worthwhile', although if you asked the arrangers on *'My Country's Got Idol Pop X Talent Factor'* they'd obviously tell you a truck driver wins every time ;-)

Comment: You've asked three questions: (1) are they worthwhile *[this seems opinion-based]*, (2) how can they be made more notable *[than what? I'm unclear on this question]*, and (3) are they good features if some listeners don't notice them *[this is very opinion-based]*. In your question, you've cited 4 reasons why you think they're not worthwhile. For this reason, the post seems more like a "rant in disguise" (to quote the help center) than a genuine question that you don't know the answer to. I've voted to close, but if you focus on the second question and remove Q1 & Q3, I'd remove my VTC.

Comment: It used to be such a formula to do that for the last chorus, didn't it? Most Eurovision songs used to do it. It's like they're worried it's getting boring. It does mean the band have to concentrate for a few moments, which maybe adds a *little* excitement. If key-changes are actually written into a song it can be great though. A Nightingale Sang in Berkeley Square does it beautifully. Stevie Wonder's Living for the City has a brilliant 3/4 middle eight where the key goes all over the place. There must be loads of great songs that change key.

Comment: @jdjazz - thanks for the reasons. It's not a rant - I seem to do this sort of change every few gigs, but my opinion isn't really part. If it is a worthwhile procedure, then what are things players might do to make it so, rather than do it in such an ephemeral way? Subtle changes such as modulations are one thing, but a lot of the time, it appears (to me) that it's almost become an exercise, trotted out, as portrayed in other comments.

Comment: The truck driver change at the end of “Love Story” by Taylor Swift is arguably the reason why I have bought all of her albums. And personally I find key changes quite easy to play, and I’m nothing even close to a Nashville session artist. Seems like that key change was literally worth it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - true, some key changes are memorable. I'm trying to elicit the reasons why. Changing chords playing on guitar isn't too onerous, but reading a change from key C to key C# or Db isn't the same when reading dots - at least for me.

Comment: I'm not any fan of the simple up-a-tone truck-driver, but I just heard this track again, which I think does it beautifully. It kind of takes you a second to see just what it did, because the melody leads same-to-same note [YouTube - Athlete: Wires](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ivKzieP9ZU)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of pop music writing and performing is about maintaining interest whilst keeping the music repetetive enough to follow (sing along to / dance to). There are lots of ways to do that - it's an art and craft all of its own - and many of the tricks used *aren't* particularly prominent, nor are they supposed to be - they're supposed to provide just enough of an incremental lift to get through the next few bars, and then the next trick is whipped out...

One way to make it more notable would be to employ another typical trick (pregnant pause, new line of instrumentation, change in the harmony vocals, change in the dancing(?)) along with the key change.

But it may be that just as your fellow road users shouldn't be too aware of your gearshifts, it's OK if your truck driver's key change smoothly blends into the performance...

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say 'Not modulations'?  A key change within a piece is a modulation.  You would still call changing the key from say C major to C minor a modulation.  As you say, key changes happen to maintain or ramp up the interest, even if for a short time.  It's usually uplifting.  Songs are usually only a few minutes long, so the effect of modulating will achieve its purpose.

Comment: I meant modulations where there's a far more subtle key change, so rather than going into relative minor, for instance, there's a less than subtle up a semitone/truck driver's gearchange type.

Answer (score 1):

Tim says : some listener even don’t realize the key change.

Well, most of us realize it and sometimes we are really longing for a change, don’t we?

The question is interesting when we ask: why do they modulate? The singer can show that his voice range is even broader. The pianists can demonstrate their ability of reading sharp and flat keys. (Don’t under estimate this point. It is very useful to practice them in a song.

Are there alternatives to modulate than the chromatic progression? I many pieces modulate a fourth up. I prefer the mediant key.

Is it necessary to notate the whole thing? Certainly not for professional dance musicians, but for amateurs, yes! Even *lesson one* starting in F, modulating to F# and G.

Finally: Why did classical composers write out the reprises of section B in the sonata form? They could have notated: The same thing ... a 4 th higher.

Modulations are worthwhile, as there is tension when remaining in the same key.

Comment: Quick anecdote: running a pop band years ago, I suggested to the singer that we change key in the middle of a song. His reply - no, I can't do that. Secretly, the rest of us decided where it would be, and did it. Afterwards I said 'well done, you did it' 'Did what?' was his reply. Maybe musos realise, but lots of others don't, I'm sure!

Comment: A change up a fourth is somewhat like what happens in a lot of choruses, and isn't really what I meant. It might show off someone's vocal range, but that's all.(To me).

Comment: @Tim haha nice. Although I'd be careful doing that with some songs - as a singer, I would be kind of upset if the band went into a key that was too high for me without telling me. Seems like the way you guys did it was perfectly fine!